# Weight у разного количества кнопок ведет себя по-разному

Tags: android, xml

Как сделать так, чтобы button с весом 3 равнялся по ширине трем кнопкам с весом  1? Красным подписан layout_weight кнопок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonHistory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="/" />
```

Comment: `layout_width` у кнопок чему равен? 0dp?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Полную xml разметку добавьте в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonHistory"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.75"
      android:text="Button" />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="0.25"
      android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте веса таким образом внутри `TableLayout`. Чтобы растянуть элемент на несколько колонок есть специальный атрибут `android:layout_span`:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonHistory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBackspace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```